# Can I pretty print the output of linearmodels.panel.results.compare() when I convert a Jupyter Notebook to PDF?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, nbconvert, linearmodels

I use Python to analyze data in Jupyter Notebooks, which I convert to PDFs to share with coauthors (`jupyter nbconvert --to pdf`).
I often use `linearmodels.panel.results.compare()` to compare panel regression estimates from the `linearmodels` package.
However, the PDF conversion process converts the `compare()` output to a fixed-width font that is much too wide for the PDF (I will provide the code below):

[image: Much too wide compare output]

Can I pretty print the output of `compare()` when I convert a Jupyter Notebook to PDF?

A possible solution is to convert the `compare()` output to a data frame.
The option `pd.options.display.latex.repr = True` pretty prints data frames when I convert to PDF.
For example:

[image: Pretty print of data frame]

In the notebook, the `compare()` output formats nicely and *looks like* a data frame.
However, it is not a data frame, and I have failed to convert it to a data frame.

Is there an alternative solution to compare the pretty print the results of `linearmodels` package output?

Here is the code that generates the tables above (copy and paste into a Jupyter Notebook code cell):

```
import pandas as pd
from linearmodels.panel import FamaMacBeth
from linearmodels.panel.results import compare

pd.options.display.latex.repr = True

from statsmodels.datasets import grunfeld
df = grunfeld.load_pandas().data
df.set_index(['firm','year'], inplace=True)

display(df.head())

table = {
    '(1)': FamaMacBeth.from_formula(formula='value ~ 1 + invest + capital', data=df).fit(),
    '(2)': FamaMacBeth.from_formula(formula='value ~ 1 + invest + capital', data=df).fit(),
    '(3)': FamaMacBeth.from_formula(formula='value ~ 1 + invest + capital', data=df).fit(),
    '(4)': FamaMacBeth.from_formula(formula='value ~ 1 + invest + capital', data=df).fit()
}

display(compare(table))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`compare` returns a `PanelModelComparison`. This class has a property `summary` which returns a `linearmodels.compat.statsmodels.Summary` which is virtually identical to the `Summary` objects available in statsmodels.  `Summary` instances have a method `as_latex()` which converts the table to LaTeX.

```py
import pandas as pd
from linearmodels.panel import FamaMacBeth
from linearmodels.panel.results import compare

pd.options.display.latex.repr = True

from statsmodels.datasets import grunfeld
df = grunfeld.load_pandas().data
df.set_index(['firm','year'], inplace=True)

display(df.head())

table = {
    '(1)': FamaMacBeth.from_formula(formula='value ~ 1 + invest + capital', data=df).fit(),
    '(2)': FamaMacBeth.from_formula(formula='value ~ 1 + invest + capital', data=df).fit(),
    '(3)': FamaMacBeth.from_formula(formula='value ~ 1 + invest + capital', data=df).fit(),
    '(4)': FamaMacBeth.from_formula(formula='value ~ 1 + invest + capital', data=df).fit()
}

display(compare(table))
comparrison = compare(table)
summary = comparrison.summary
print(summary.as_latex())
```

This prints

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lcccc}
\toprule
                               &         \textbf{(1)}        &         \textbf{(2)}        &         \textbf{(3)}        &         \textbf{(4)}         \\
\midrule
\textbf{Dep. Variable}         &            value            &            value            &            value            &            value             \\
\textbf{Estimator}             &         FamaMacBeth         &         FamaMacBeth         &         FamaMacBeth         &         FamaMacBeth          \\
\textbf{No. Observations}      &             220             &             220             &             220             &             220              \\
\textbf{Cov. Est.}             &  Fama-MacBeth Standard Cov  &  Fama-MacBeth Standard Cov  &  Fama-MacBeth Standard Cov  &  Fama-MacBeth Standard Cov   \\
\textbf{R-squared}             &            0.6964           &            0.6964           &            0.6964           &            0.6964            \\
\textbf{R-Squared (Within)}    &           -1.8012           &           -1.8012           &           -1.8012           &           -1.8012            \\
\textbf{R-Squared (Between)}   &            0.8660           &            0.8660           &            0.8660           &            0.8660            \\
\textbf{R-Squared (Overall)}   &            0.6964           &            0.6964           &            0.6964           &            0.6964            \\
\textbf{F-statistic}           &            248.83           &            248.83           &            248.83           &            248.83            \\
\textbf{P-value (F-stat)}      &            0.0000           &            0.0000           &            0.0000           &            0.0000            \\
\textbf{=====================} & =========================== & =========================== & =========================== & ===========================  \\
\textbf{Intercept}             &            114.16           &            114.16           &            114.16           &            114.16            \\
\textbf{ }                     &           (3.8390)          &           (3.8390)          &           (3.8390)          &           (3.8390)           \\
\textbf{capital}               &            0.1457           &            0.1457           &            0.1457           &            0.1457            \\
\textbf{ }                     &           (0.8510)          &           (0.8510)          &           (0.8510)          &           (0.8510)           \\
\textbf{invest}                &            6.3899           &            6.3899           &            6.3899           &            6.3899            \\
\textbf{ }                     &           (11.618)          &           (11.618)          &           (11.618)          &           (11.618)           \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
%\caption{Model Comparison}
\end{center}

T-stats reported in parentheses
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative that uses Kevin S.'s `.summary.as_latex()`.
The function below uses `compare().summary` to create a data frame, which `jupyter nbconvert --to pdf` converts to a table.

```
from io import StringIO
import warnings

def compare_df(x, fit_stats=['Estimator', 'R-squared', 'No. Observations']):
    with warnings.catch_warnings():
        warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=FutureWarning)
        y = pd.read_csv(StringIO(compare(x, stars=True).summary.as_csv()), skiprows=1, skipfooter=1, engine='python')
    z = pd.DataFrame(
        data=y.iloc[:, 1:].values,
        index=y.iloc[:, 0].str.strip(),
        columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(
            arrays=[y.columns[1:], y.iloc[0][1:]],
            names=['Model', 'Dep. Var.']
        )
    )
    return pd.concat([z.iloc[11:], z.loc[fit_stats]])
```

The PDF output is:

[image: Pretty table]

Note this solution requires `pd.options.display.latex.repr = True`.